# What does A485 mean? And what does the values on the y-axis expresses?

Tags: acid-base, notation

This question is from past exam paper. I don't want an answer to the multiple choice question below, I just want to understand what A<sub>485</sub> means in the context of the question.

[image: it is a multiple choice question]

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.‎

Comment: I did try the question but I am not getting what is A485 and 485nm, how this is related to this question and what are the steps to be taken to get the answer.

Comment: Then do as instructed; put in precise details of **everything** you did. Then I'll vote to reopen your question so it'd get answered.

Comment: Am I okay now, sir?

Comment: What did you do that didn't get answers? Enlighten us by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: I got it. I think, I don't need to edit the question. May be, if I ask next time any question I will try to ask according to the instruction.

Comment: @Ahmad For further reference, please also keep the following in mind: A screenshot or picture of an exercise is not searchable. Please consider rewriting it, so that it can be of help for future visitors. Further I invite you to take the [tour] to learn about the site and review the [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141).

Answer (score 2):

$A_{485}$ means the same thing as the text of the multiple choice question "absorbance of the solution at 485 nm".

"nm" is an abbreviation for nanometers.

In other words, the absorbance of light having a wavelength of 485 nanometers is plotted on the y-axis of the graphs.